# Callstack of exception from unmanaged code called by PInvoke in C#

Tags: pinvoke

is there any way to get callstack of exception from unmanaged code in C# which calls unmanaged by pinvoke. Ideally without any modification of unmanaged code.

```
[DllImport("Configurator.CIntf.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int createConfigurator();

try
{
     createConfigurator()
}
catch ( Exception e)
{
     //Get callstack in unmanaged code
}
```

Comment: Er, the unmanaged code is contracted not to throw exceptions. Fix that.

Comment: I have found almost the same question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850443/how-to-obtain-the-native-stacktrace-from-native-exceptions-caught-in-managed-cod